# AXIOM 1.2.13 to 1.2.20 migration

Tags: axiom

```
I have the following Java method using AXIOM 1.2.13:

private OMElement createSecurityHeader(String username, String password) {
OMNamespaceImpl wsseNS = new OMNamespaceImpl(WSSE_NS, WSSE_PREFIX);
OMFactory factory = new SOAP11Factory();
OMElementImpl securityHeader;
OMElementImpl usernameTokenElement;
OMElementImpl usernameElement;
OMElementImpl passwordElement;

// create the Security header block
securityHeader = new OMElementImpl("Security", wsseNS, factory);
securityHeader.addAttribute("mustUnderstand", "1", null);

// nest the UsernameToken in the Security header
usernameTokenElement = new OMElementImpl(USERNAME_TOKEN_LN, wsseNS, securityHeader, factory);

// nest the Username and Password elements
usernameElement = new OMElementImpl(USERNAME_LN, wsseNS, usernameTokenElement, factory);
usernameElement.setText(username);

passwordElement = new OMElementImpl(PASSWORD_LN, wsseNS,usernameTokenElement, factory);
passwordElement.setText(password);
passwordElement.addAttribute(PASSWORD_TYPE_ATTR, PASSWORD_TEXT, null);

return securityHeader;
}
}
```

I want to migrate this code to work with AXIOM 1.2.20.

Looking for a solution or what resources are recommended to do this in general?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`OMAbstractFactory.getSOAP11Factory()`](https://ws.apache.org/axiom/apidocs/org/apache/axiom/om/OMAbstractFactory.html#getSOAP11Factory()) to get the SOAPFactory instance, then rewrite your code to use the factory methods until there are no more references to internal implementation classes. The resulting code will then work with both Axiom versions.